# Kafka, nodejs client (kafkaesque) socket default timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, apache-storm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. a nodejs ->kafkaesque(kafka nodejs client)->kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1->storm. In Kafkaesque,(kafka nodejs client), I notice in api.js, there are following line to create socket.

```
 _socket = net.createConnection(_options.port, _options.host);
```

I am wondering what's the default value for timeout of socket. Shall I setTimeout(0) if I want socket connection is always there/permanent.

I also notice following line in the later part of the codes:

```
_socket.on('timeout', function(){
      console.log('socket timeout');
    });
```

if I want the socket connection permanent, shall I try to make connection again in this timeout function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`net` docs for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback):

> By default net.Socket do not have a timeout.

So unless there's a `socket.setTimeout()` call somewhere else, the socket should not have a timeout.

Additionally:

> When an idle timeout is triggered the socket will receive a 'timeout' event but the connection will not be severed. The user must manually end() or destroy() the socket.

So you do not need to reconnect when the `timeout` event fires unless the callback is disconnecting with `end()` or `destroy()`.

Comment: But I got error "This socket has been ended by the other party", I using command netstat -anp | grep 9092, I could not see port 9092 binding to any protocol. 9092 is my kafka port.

Comment: "ended by other party" does not sound like a timeout on the initiator's end. It sounds like the connection was closed at the other end.

Comment: So do you mean Kafka ends the connection? In my case, the system is idle for more than 5 hours or 10 hours. Could Kafka ends the connection since there is no messages pushed to the queue. So I shall add something in                   _socket.on('close', function(){
      //console.log('socket close');
    });